How can I compute and visualise the best two-colour basis in LAB colour space for an image
I'm interested in working with images of monochrome drawings, which typically have a paper colour and a "pencil" colour. Let's say something like the image at this link, where the paper is a cream colour and the pencil is actually red chalk:
https://www.rct.uk/collection/912778/archers-shooting-at-a-herm
Every pixel in the image lies somewhere on the line between the colours "cream" and "red chalk". Given this assumption (that each pixel colour is a convex combination of cream and red chalk) I want to encode the image as a greyscale bitmap combined with a colour lookup function, like a LUT.
I could just use the L channel of the image to create the greyscale version. Presumably that would work. Is there a better way, maybe determining a line segment (gradient) in colour space and mapping each pixel to the closest point on the segment? One issue is that the accuracy of this fit seems to be a bit difficult to visualize, because a LAB colour space is 3D. Obviously I can calculate the error in the result numerically, but I'd like to be able to see where the pixels are in LAB space.

you can define points in 3D, forming a line, and then you can project any point onto the line and determine its parameter (0 to 1, also exceeding those) along the line. -- visualization... that's a generic point cloud, perhaps drawn with semitransparent points, or a visualization of the "volume" (3D histogram), again proportional to density

Out of curiosity why do you want to assume that the colours are exact combinations of the two extremes. You surely want to pick the 256 for 8 bit (or 1024 for 10 bit) set of colours that minimises the residual error in the monochrome image + LUT relative to the colour original. One simple method is to use a greedy algorithm on the most frequent colours and then divide the remaining bins across the intervening values. Add in a bit of error diffusion and you can get something that looks pretty convincing. Consider green paper and red chalk as a more complex example.

That is a very reasonable question. I'm interested in separating the colour gradient from the image data because I am investigating duotone effects. These are inspired by the physical duotone process of combining screens printed in inks of two distinct colours. I guess the question generalizes to tritone, quadtone etc, but for these mono drawings two "inks" seems like it should be enough.
